Discretization with leapfrog
I have a system with some Coulomb forces but also some viscous terms. The ODE reads
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= v \\
\dot{v} &= F_1(x,\sigma) \\
\dot{\sigma} &= F_2(x,v,\sigma)\,.
\end{align}
If $\sigma = \text{const}$ it is clear that I can use the leapfrog scheme for the positions $x$ (or velocity Verlet to obtain velocities as well). However, what can I do about my stresses $\sigma$ which depend on the velocities $v$?
I tried differentiating with time $\dot\sigma$, and after some messy substitutions I reach an ODE of the form
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= v \\
\dot{v} &= F_1(x,\sigma) \\
\dot{\sigma} &= \delta \\
\dot{\delta} &= F_3(x,v,\sigma)\,.
\end{align}
Now, if only $F_3$ did not depend on $v$! Since my system has a dissipative term, it seems that it cannot be written in any conservative/symplectic/symmetric form. Is RK4 my only option here? I've seen one author who used leapfrog for the positions and discretized the stress $\sigma$ separately with a second order scheme. This leads to a second order scheme overall, but are all these nice properties of leapfrog maintained (perhaps only for $x,v$ but not $\sigma$)? Any insight regarding my discretization options is welcome.

For non-conservative systems it makes almost no difference if you use Verlet or any other second order method like Heun or the midpoint method. RK4 is 4th order with a slightly larger stability region, allowing larger step sizes.
